# Number Theoretic sum

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Find the number of rational numbers m/n,where m,n are relatively prime positive integers satisfying m < n and mn=25!.

I cannot think out how to do it.Please help.

Comment: Satisfying what?

Comment: Your post seems incomplete. Please provide a better description of the problem

Comment: soorryy...now u can see...

Comment: http://perplexus.info/show.php?pid=4883&cid=34517

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice $$25! = 2^{22} \times 3^{10} \times 5^6 \times 7^3 \times 11^2 \times 13 \times 17 \times 19 \times 23$$ contains 9 primes and there is a $1$-$1$ correspondence between picking a pair of $(m,n)$ with $\gcd(m,n) = 1$ and $mn = 25!$ and forming a subset from these 9 primes. Half of these pair has $m > n$ and the other half $m < n$. So the answer is $2^9/2 = 256$.